# Get previous URL in a JSP tag

Tags: java, jsp, url, get, jstl

I want to do an if statement in a JSP tag so if the previous URL sting is = 0 or empty then don't display something. Im trying to use refererPAge but its not working. Can anybody help. I cant even get it to display the previous URL

```
    <c:set var="refererPage" scope="request" value="${request.getHeader}"/>
    <c:out value="${refererPage}"/>
    ${refererPage}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that request.getHeader is actually returning anything? A request header contains a bunch of different properties. They're described here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_client_request.htm

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: in JSTL using something like ${request.getHeader} is a bit redundant since using the dot operator is an implicit getter function.

So outside of using if test={(param name) not empty} (This is a null check), try request.referer or request.getHeader['referer']

Comment: doesn't return anything in page, as already tried that
    <c:set var="refererPage" scope="request" value="${request.getHeader['referer']}"/>
  <c:out value="${refererPage}"/>
  ${refererPage}

Comment: I think I figured it out. The 'referer' header property won't exist in the request header if you're hitting a page via browser url and not a link or a redirect. So if I'm reading your question right, you aren't getting any value for your referer because there is no referer.

If you open your browser console and hit a page via URL then check the request header you'll see what I'm getting at

Comment: yeh dont think that works sorry

Answer (score 2):

following thing will help you to solve your problem.

```
${header.referer}
```